Updates not working due to mariadb and mysql troubles
Ever since updating to Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS I've been unable to make any updates, install new apps, or even remove old apps.
Everything errors out saying "unmet dependencies."
Even when I try to repair the packages system I get an error saying it can't stop mysql because it's not loaded.
sudo apt --fix-broken install returns the following.
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  acpi-support acpid aisleriot apturl apturl-common branding-ubuntu cheese
  cheese-common chromium-codecs-ffmpeg-extra cpp-11 endeavour endeavour-common
  fonts-kacst fonts-kacst-one fonts-khmeros-core fonts-lao fonts-liberation2
  fonts-lklug-sinhala fonts-sil-abyssinica fonts-sil-padauk fonts-thai-tlwg
  fonts-tibetan-machine fonts-tlwg-garuda fonts-tlwg-garuda-ttf
  fonts-tlwg-kinnari fonts-tlwg-kinnari-ttf fonts-tlwg-laksaman
  fonts-tlwg-laksaman-ttf fonts-tlwg-loma fonts-tlwg-loma-ttf fonts-tlwg-mono
  fonts-tlwg-mono-ttf fonts-tlwg-norasi fonts-tlwg-norasi-ttf
  fonts-tlwg-purisa fonts-tlwg-purisa-ttf fonts-tlwg-sawasdee
  fonts-tlwg-sawasdee-ttf fonts-tlwg-typewriter fonts-tlwg-typewriter-ttf
  fonts-tlwg-typist fonts-tlwg-typist-ttf fonts-tlwg-typo fonts-tlwg-typo-ttf
  fonts-tlwg-umpush fonts-tlwg-umpush-ttf fonts-tlwg-waree
  fonts-tlwg-waree-ttf gcc-11 gcc-11-base gcc-12-base:i386 gedit gedit-common
  genisoimage gir1.2-amtk-5 gir1.2-appindicator3-0.1 gir1.2-gck-1 gir1.2-gcr-3
  gir1.2-goa-1.0 gir1.2-gtksource-300 gir1.2-gtksource-4 gir1.2-gweather-3.0
  gir1.2-javascriptcoregtk-4.0 gir1.2-json-1.0 gir1.2-nma-1.0 gir1.2-snapd-1
  gir1.2-soup-2.4 gir1.2-tepl-6 gir1.2-webkit2-4.0 gnome-bluetooth
  gnome-bluetooth-common gnome-mahjongg gnome-mines gnome-sudoku gnome-todo
  gnome-video-effects gsfonts gstreamer1.0-clutter-3.0 guile-2.2-libs
  guile-3.0-libs irqbalance libabsl20210324 libapache2-mod-php libappstream4
  libasan6 libatk1.0-data libavcodec58 libavfilter7 libavformat58 libavutil56
  libblockdev-crypto2 libblockdev-fs2 libblockdev-loop2 libblockdev-part-err2
  libblockdev-part2 libblockdev-swap2 libblockdev-utils2 libblockdev2
  libboost-filesystem1.74.0 libboost-iostreams1.74.0 libboost-locale1.74.0
  libboost-python1.74.0 libboost-python1.83.0 libboost-regex1.74.0
  libboost-thread1.74.0 libbpf0 libcamel-1.2-63 libcbor0.8 libcheese-gtk25
  libcheese8 libclutter-1.0-0 libclutter-1.0-common libclutter-gst-3.0-0
  libclutter-gtk-1.0-0 libcodec2-1.0 libcogl-common libcogl-pango20
  libcogl-path20 libcogl20 libcolamd2 libcolord-gtk1t64 libcupsfilters1
  libdav1d5 libdazzle-1.0-0 libdazzle-common libdmapsharing-3.0-2
  libdns-export1110 libebackend-1.2-10 libebook-1.2-20 libebook-contacts-1.2-3
  libecal-2.0-1 libedata-book-1.2-26 libedata-cal-2.0-1 libedataserver-1.2-26
  libedataserverui-1.2-3 libflac8 libfontembed1 libfreerdp-client2-2t64
  libfreerdp-server2-2t64 libfreerdp2-2t64 libgc1 libgcab-1.0-0 libgcc-11-dev
  libgedit-amtk-5-0 libgedit-amtk-5-common libgedit-gtksourceview-300-0
  libgedit-gtksourceview-300-common libgeocode-glib0 libgfapi0 libgfrpc0
  libgfxdr0 libglusterfs0 libgnome-bluetooth13t64 libgnome-games-support-1-3
  libgnome-games-support-common libgnome-todo libgoa-backend-1.0-1
  libgssdp-1.2-0 libgtksourceview-4-0 libgtksourceview-4-common libgupnp-1.2-1
  libgweather-3-16 libgweather-common libicu70 libilmbase25 libisc-export1105
  libjavascriptcoregtk-4.0-18 libldap-2.5-0 libllvm15t64 liblua5.3-0
  libmagickcore-6.q16-6 libmagickcore-6.q16-6-extra libmagickwand-6.q16-6
  libmessaging-menu0 libmozjs-91-0 libmpdec3 libnautilus-extension1a
  libnetpbm10 libnetplan0 libnfs13 libnsl-dev libopencore-amrnb0
  libopencore-amrwb0 libopenexr25 liborcus-0.17-0 liborcus-parser-0.17-0
  libpcre3 libperl5.34 libplist3 libpoppler118 libpostproc55 libprotobuf23
  libpython3.10 libpython3.10-minimal libpython3.10-stdlib libqpdf28
  libqqwing2v5 libraw20 libreoffice-pdfimport librest-0.7-0
  librygel-core-2.6-2 librygel-db-2.6-2 librygel-renderer-2.6-2
  librygel-server-2.6-2 libsmbios-c2 libsnapd-glib1 libsoup-gnome-2.4-1
  libsrt1.4-gnutls libsuitesparseconfig5 libswresample3 libswscale5
  libtepl-6-4 libtepl-common libtiff5 libtirpc-dev libtorrent-rasterbar2.0t64
  libtsan0 libunistring2 libunistring2:i386 libvncserver1 libvpx7
  libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37 libwinpr2-2t64 libx264-163 linux-headers-5.15.0-122
  linux-headers-5.15.0-122-generic linux-hwe-6.8-headers-6.8.0-40
  linux-hwe-6.8-headers-6.8.0-45 linux-hwe-6.8-tools-6.8.0-40
  linux-hwe-6.8-tools-6.8.0-45 linux-image-5.15.0-122-generic
  linux-modules-5.15.0-122-generic linux-modules-extra-5.15.0-122-generic
  nautilus-share perl-modules-5.34 python3-future python3-lib2to3
  python3-libtorrent python3-lockfile python3-macaroonbakery python3-protobuf
  python3-pyatspi python3-pymacaroons python3-requests-toolbelt
  python3-rfc3339 python3.10 python3.10-minimal ubuntu-advantage-tools
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  mariadb-server
Suggested packages:
  mailx mariadb-test
The following packages will be upgraded:
  mariadb-server
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 25 not upgraded.
5 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/3,381 kB of archives.
After this operation, 55.4 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Preconfiguring packages ...
(Reading database ... 343792 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../mariadb-server_1%3a10.11.8-0ubuntu0.24.04.1_amd64.deb ..
.
Failed to stop mysql.service: Unit mysql.service not loaded.
invoke-rc.d: initscript mysql, action "stop" failed.
Attempt to stop MariaDB/MySQL server returned exitcode 5
There is a MariaDB/MySQL server running, but we failed in our attempts to stop i
t.
Stop it yourself and try again!
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/mariadb-server_1%3a10.11.
8-0ubuntu0.24.04.1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 new mariadb-server package pre-installation script subprocess returned error ex
it status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/mariadb-server_1%3a10.11.8-0ubuntu0.24.04.1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

I've tried purging mysql and mariadb both several times, and nothing works.
I've been at this every night for a week and can't get anything to fix it. I'm about to just reinstall, but I'd much rather figure out how to fix it.

What happens if you run 'sudo service mysql stop' or failing that running the control script directly 'sudo /etc/init.d/mysql stop'  and then 'sudo apt --fix-broken install' as you did last time

Failed to stop mysql.service: Unit mysql.service not loaded.

Sorry to hear it failed. Take a look at the answer at this link. This suggest there is a bug if 'akonadi' is running https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=1050416 that affects other Debian route OS such as Ubuntu: - https://superuser.com/questions/1822192/cannot-install-mariadb-server-on-debian-there-is-a-mariadb-mysql-server-running

This question is similar to: How do I restore the default repositories?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
